# mongodump 2.6.3 locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid

Tags: mongodb, upstart

I face a similar problem as

[mongodump failure 'locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19005990/mongodump-failure-localefacet-s-create-c-locale-name-not-valid)

[mongodump failure 'locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19005990/mongodump-failure-localefacet-s-create-c-locale-name-not-valid)

[MongoDB: locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19668570/cannot-start-mongodb-stdexception-localefacet-s-create-c-locale-name-not)

I tried exporting both `LC_ALL=C` and `LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"` in my `.profile` but that didn't fix it.
I tried the dpkg-reconfigure command.

I thought that mongodb needed to be started with these exports on so I edited the `/etc/init.d/mongodb` script to do the export when ran by putting it at the top. That didn't work.

So I tried at exporting globally by adding the export to `/etc/profile`.

That didn't work either. Has anyone have hints on how to debug that problem, instead of trying every possible command?

Much appreciated.